# PHP Load section of page instead of entire page with links

Tags: php, html

I have a website where i have multiple pages of contact that i add daily. The website is coded in PHP and the links go as such. `www.domain.com/home/1`, `www.domain.com/home/2`, `www.domain.com/home/3` depended on the page.

How can i make it so that when i click the next button that takes you to the next page so that it doesn't load the entire web page but only that `<div>` or section of the site that has this content. But would still keep the same link format such as `www.domain.com/home/#`

I don't want to use a iframe because i don't think i can have these links and the whole point is to make the loading seamless.

I am so lost the only thing i found is iframes but i don't want to use that.

Comment: Checkout JQuery's ajax and DOM manipulation.

Comment: Use ajax try to read this page and learn how to implement it... its easy to learn and reusable for your projects soon http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [Twitter Bootstrap tabs](http://www.mightywebdeveloper.com/coding/bootstrap-2-tabs-jquery-load-content/) or [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html).

Or check out jQuery Ajax and DOM manipulation: [Best way of loading external page with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046933/best-way-of-loading-external-page-with-ajax)